# GWT Development Mode error

Tags: java, exception, gwt, inetaddress, development-mode

When i try to execute the project, even the default "Web Application Project", I receive this error:

`INFO: Module instance default is running at localhost:8888
apr 07, 2014 9:02:46 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at localhost:8888/_ah/admin
apr 07, 2014 11:02:46 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
Exception in thread "Code server listener" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid host wildcard specification
    at java.net.SocketPermission.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketPermission.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostFromNameService(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserListener$1.run(BrowserListener.java:78)`

How can i resolve this error? 
Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me like you have network configuration issue. Basically, GWT cannot resolve the name of your browser based on its IP address.

Comment: did u check on port no.8888,no other service was running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get this error after first successful run? if yes then stop already running server instance and then restart the server.

Comment: i get this error even with the default "Web Application Starter Project"

Comment: RESOLVED ( Thanks to Niks) : uncheck AppEngine in the Eclipse project's settings